# Expression Web 4 not installing on Windows 8 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-8

I tried installing Expression Web 4 on Windows 8, but the install progress bar seems to go in reverse and then I get the following log. Any ideas on what I can do to get it fixed?

[Here is the code (online at Google Drive, live).](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18tbPKGR1MWEZx4PFzgjdCiGd5B4On2NwIceUccHpNxw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You get error 0x80070570 which means a file is corrupt.

```
10:18:55 PM Thursday, October 16, 2014: An error occurred installing the Web_en.msi package. Error: An error occured during the installation of assembly component {20FA8C1E-7DD4-43B6-AC3E-A0B20BF5AF33}. HRESULT: 0x80070570.
```

Run chkdsk and make sure the ISO of Expression Web 4 is fine (compare the hashes).

Comment: Is there a reason why the file is corrupt? It's from Microsoft's site.

Comment: Have you confirmed its corrupt?

Comment: I would think so, based on what I have seen and tried. But my Windows 8 Enterprise is not yet activated with a code, could that be why?

Comment: calculate the hash of the ISO and check it with the data Microsoft provides.